# xrandr failed to get size of gamma for output defualt

Tags: command-line, display, gnome-terminal, display-resolution, xrandr

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 (codename : disco) Intel G2030 4GB DDR3 Ram no GPU (only intel onboard graphics) I didnt install **any** drivers just checked "Install third party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats" when installing Ubuntu (and dual booting between it and Windows 10) when i try to set a custom resolution to my display it says

```
:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1368 x 768
default connected primary 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768       0.00* 
   640x480        0.00  
   1368x768       0.00  
:~$ cvt 1600 900 60
# 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
:~$ xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
:~$ xrandr --addmode default "1600x900_60.00"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Then the option becomes avalable at the resolution menu but when i change it nothing happens it stays the same

Monitor is connected using VGA

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out to be just me booting of the recovery mode everytime (see why in my previous question) so i updated ubuntu to 19.10 and everything seems to be working