# xrandr: failed to get size of gamma for output default after update

Tags: boot, xrandr

I've had the same problem on two machines running 18.04.      In each case, after an upgrade, two bad things happened:   1) the machine hung on bootup, and the only way I have been able to boot was in recovery mode.    2) when I try to connect to an external monitor I get the message that many have reported:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      0.00*
```

Also, on one one of the machines, but not the other, the default font size is huge.  I read on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201017/xrandr-failed-to-get-size-of-gamma-for-output-defualt) that this problem with `xrandr` might be caused by booting in recovery mode.   Does this sound plausible?     If so, I'm wondering how to fix the boot problem so that I can boot again.      Could somebody advise about what diagnostics I could provide so that I can get help with the hanging boot?    Thanks for any advice!